# Mount Physical Drive to VMWare Server

Tags: mount, vmware-server, physical-to-virtual

I'm running VMWare Server 2.0.2 on Server 2008 (Standard). I can also run Hyper-V if I need to.

Anyways, I have three old hard drives that came out from our previous Cent OS system. I wanted to read some of those data using a VM. Is there a way I can mount those drives to a CentOS VM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.kelvinism.com/howtos/using-raw-disks-vmware-server-2/